# How to get all properties of .class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm searching for something that works like [BeanUtils.describe](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#describe%28java.lang.Object%29), but working on `.class`, not object ? Anybody help ? Currently i'm working on list of objects class with default getHeaders method like below.

```
public class SimpleList<E>  {
    protected final Class<E> clazz;

    SimpleList(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public String[] getHeaders() {
        Map props = BeanUtils.describe(clazz); // replace this with something
        return (String[]) props.keySet().toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you **can't** use `E.class` and there's also no "workaround" to this, *unless* you have access to a `Class<E>` that got passed to you in some way.

Comment: @Sean, I just noticed after I wondered "Why is this tagged [tag:generics]?" ;-)

Comment: @Joachim You're right. I Corrected this now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`Introspector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) API:

```
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = 
    Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass).getPropertyDescriptors();
List<String> propertyNames = new ArrayList<String>(propertyDescriptors.length);
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
    propertyNames.add(propertyDescriptor.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You pretty much want [`PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28java.lang.Class%29). It returns an array of [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) objects, of which you'd need to extract the names.

Comment: Note that the answer from @Sean works without requiring the BeanUtils library and the invocation is only *a tiny bit* longer.